# Samsung SM-T320 battery issue reboot loop

Tags: samsung, battery, boot-loop, reboot

I own a Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 Wifi (SM-T320), with LineageOS 20 (Android 13).

I always had a weird behaviour with this tablet. When the tablet battery value is between 25% to 29%, the screen flicker, and it shuts down, Then, it reboots loop.

If I plug in my charger, the battery value is equal to the value before it reboots loop. If if do nothing, it reboots loop until it stops, and the battery value is lower than 5%.

The weird thing is that when I reboot to TWRP, the battery value is equal to the value before the reboot loop process, and if I let the tablet with TWRP open, it stays in power for more than a hour, with the screen brightness to max. So the battery health is not the issue here.

I tried the calibration process (recharge to 100%, drain the battery, go to TWRP and delete batterystats.bin, than reboot), but the issue is still here.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The battery health can still be a problem (and considering that your device is 10 years old a very likely): while the capacity of your battery is still not bad the maximum power (ampere) it can deliver in a short time when it is below 30% seems to be the problem. If screen + CPU and whatever draw to much power the voltage breaks in. In the beginning the voltage breaks only affect the screen, later also the CPU which crashes. A reboot requires a lot of power in a short time, this causes again a voltage drop and the CPU fails which you see by the reboot loop.

Comment: I forget to mention, I changed the stock battery from Samsung with another similar battery, and both of them had the same issues. Then it stops to reboot loop, and I plug in my charger, the battery screen (before loading) shows that the battery has more than 20% energy. And in TWRP, the device stays in power for more than a hour. When the battery value reaches 0%, it stays in power until the value is blank, and then for a couple of minutes, it shuts down completely.